# Bar Chart Python

Tags: python, numpy

I am supposed to print a Bar Chart, I had tried using this code [:10], however i am not sure why isn't it working. And also how to print the top 10.

```
location_uid, count = np.unique(data['locationid'], return_counts=True)
location_uid = np.require(location_uid, dtype=np.int)
n_wifi_locs = len(location_uid)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (15, 8))
idx = np.argsort(count)[::-1]

dummy = ax.bar(np.arange(n_wifi_locs),count[idx],align='center',alpha=0.4)
dummy = ax.set_xticks(np.arange(n_wifi_locs))
dummy = ax.set_xticklabels(location_uid[idx])
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it isn't working"?

Comment: because i tried inserting the [:10] to display the only 10 bar charts and there is no difference...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have access to your data, so I generated some random. I just modified `idx`, to keep only the 10 first. I also used `np.arange(10)` because we just plot 10 values.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

location_uid, count = np.unique(np.random.randint(0, 20, 1000), return_counts=True)
location_uid = np.require(location_uid, dtype=np.int)
n_wifi_locs = len(location_uid)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (15, 8))
idx = np.argsort(count)[::-1][:10]

dummy = ax.bar(np.arange(10), count[idx], align='center',alpha=0.4)
dummy = ax.set_xticks(np.arange(10))
dummy = ax.set_xticklabels(location_uid[idx])
```

Comment: You should add the line "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt", I think.